# Postgresql Indexing in array search

Tags: postgresql

When array size bigger than 5 searching in seq if lower index scan. Why?

`explain select * from collection_attributes ca where  ca."type" IN (10,20, 30, 60,70)`

**result**

```
  Bitmap Heap Scan on collection_attributes ca  (cost=373.71..1974.97 rows=26354 width=92) (actual time=0.669..4.707 rows=26542 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (type = ANY ('{10,20,30,60,70}'::integer[]))
  Heap Blocks: exact=1082
  Buffers: shared hit=1140
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on collection_attributes_type_index  (cost=0.00..367.12 rows=26354 width=0) (actual time=0.571..0.572 rows=27597 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (type = ANY ('{10,20,30,60,70}'::integer[]))
        Buffers: shared hit=58
Planning Time: 0.059 ms
Execution Time: 5.557 ms
```

But

`explain select * from collection_attributes ca where  ca."type" IN (10,20, 30, 60,70, 80);`

**result**

```
  Seq Scan on collection_attributes ca  (cost=0.00..2375.09 rows=43841 width=92) (actual time=0.006..8.495 rows=44114 loops=1)
  Filter: (type = ANY ('{10,20,30,60,70,80}'::integer[]))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 24831
  Buffers: shared hit=1173
Planning Time: 0.060 ms
Execution Time: 9.904 ms
```

**I need index search all size of array**

Comment: Because it thinks it will be faster that way.  Maybe it really is faster that way: we don't know as you didn't give us any useful information, like `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, or how big the table is.

Comment: question updated with new explain @jjanes

Comment: Second query finds over 60% of all records in the table, an index scan would be the worst option

Comment: The seq scan takes 80% longer to find 66% more rows. That is pretty much a wash.  Not worth worrying about.   If you think the difference will get larger as you scale up, then you need to measure on the scaled up case.

Comment: You need abandon the idea that index processing is always faster. Keep in mind that an index is a physical thing, stored on disk. Processing it requires physical I/O operations and random I/O on the main table. At some point in the percentage data of interest the I/O time (cost) overcomes the penalty (cost) of sequential processing the main table. Beyond that point sequential processing is faster, sometimes much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice between `Seq Scan` and an `index access` is done by the optimizer based on the calculated cost.

The `Seq Scan` for a non trivial table has a rather high cost, but it is constant, independent of the filter condition.

On the contrary the index access to select a small number of rows has a very low cost, but it increase linear with the number of selected rows. For some percentage of the selected rows of a table the **cost of an index access will inevitable increase the cost of sequential scan** - *this is what you observe*.

**Illustration Example**

```
create table test as
select 
mod(id,10)*10 type,
rpad('x',87,'y') pad
from generate_series(1,10000000) t(id)
;

create index test_idx on test(type);
analyze  test;
```

**Index Access**

To get the row with `type in (10)`  the optimizer choose the `Bitmap Heap Scan`  with cost of `266174.50`

```
explain analyze
select * from test where type in (10);

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=11259.68..266174.50 rows=1011000 width=92) (actual time=65.373..1086.653 rows=1000000 loops=1)   |
  Recheck Cond: (type = 10)                                                                                                      |
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5780991                                                                                         |
  Heap Blocks: exact=55027 lossy=98820                                                                                           |
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_idx  (cost=0.00..11006.93 rows=1011000 width=0) (actual time=51.336..51.337 rows=1000000 loops=1)|
        Index Cond: (type = 10)                                                                                                  |
Planning Time: 0.068 ms                                                                                                          |
...                     |
Execution Time: 1125.095 ms
```

**Seq Scan**

While selecting `type in (10, 20)` the sequential scan is choosen with cost of `278847.00`

```
explain analyze
select * from test where type in (10, 20);

QUERY PLAN                                                                                                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..278847.00 rows=2025333 width=92) (actual time=1.783..1069.878 rows=2000000 loops=1)|
  Filter: (type = ANY ('{10,20}'::integer[]))                                                                    |
  Rows Removed by Filter: 8000000                                                                                |
Planning Time: 0.065 ms                                                                                          |
...
Execution Time: 1132.009 ms
```

You may verify why when you disable the sequential scan with `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;`

The plan used index but has a higher cost than the previous plan with Seq scan and therefore **is not selected by default**

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=21925.21..279540.57 rows=2025333 width=92) (actual time=87.542..1265.229 rows=2000000 loops=1)   |
  Recheck Cond: (type = ANY ('{10,20}'::integer[]))                                                                              |
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5138682                                                                                         |
  Heap Blocks: exact=55027 lossy=98820                                                                                           |
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_idx  (cost=0.00..21418.87 rows=2025333 width=0) (actual time=73.613..73.613 rows=2000000 loops=1)|
        Index Cond: (type = ANY ('{10,20}'::integer[]))                                                                          |
Planning Time: 0.073 ms                                                                                                          |
...
Execution Time: 1342.678 ms
```

> I need index search all size of array

Considering the above discussion you should elabore why do you need this...