# Postgresql not always using index

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using version 11.6. I have a table with a column named order_status (int2) with a b-tree index on it. Here is a count of how many times each number appears.

```
order_status|count |
------------+------+
           0|197739|
           1|465879|
           4| 59133|
           5|  4883|
```

If I run a query `select * from tbl_order where order_status = 0`, it uses the index (same for `4` and `5`). But if I query for `order_status = 1` it does a sequential scan. Am I to understand that, because the bulk of the rows have `order_status == 1` that it's more economical to just scan the whole table rather than consult the index?

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75724707/4808122)

Comment: Another weird thing is if I query `order_status' equal to `4` or `5` individually, it uses the index (like I said), but if I run `order_status in (4,5)`, it will do a full table scan.

Comment: What query plan is faster for value 1? And index scan (use "set enable_seqscan to off" first) or the current sequential read? Use explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) to get the plan and the execution details. And please add them in plain text to your original question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the DB engine needs to read your index (a sort of a table) find all row_ids with the criteria you have provided, then read the actual table and filter by those row_ids. If the number of rows to filter exceeds certain percent, it is more reasonable (for DB engine) to do a full scan. Those calculation are based on statistics collected from time to time for all tables.
There can be of course an incorrect estimation. Not sure if postgres has recalculate statistics on the table command but you can try to find one.